# Action Bar like the Books app

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar

In Honeycomb, the Books Action Bar fades in/out when the user taps on the screen, appearing/disappearing over other layout content.

How is this done?

Comment: Does it appear over other layout content or does the screen resize for it?

Comment: @Berdon It appears over other layout content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set this as your application or activity theme:

```
<style name="Theme.OverlayActionBar" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Then you can use `ActionBar.hide()` and `show()` as in Berdons answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can add/hide ActionBars programmatically with ([Source](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding)):

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.hide();
actionBar.show();
```

**Edit:**

You might even be able to go so far as to pull the ActionBar view from the parent and re-add it so it "floats" (RelativeLayout as the container).

**Edit 3:**

Hmm... How about using a negative top margin on your activity layout and then using show/hide?

Comment: hide/show does not produce the same effect. How exactly would you do what you suggest on the edit?

Comment: I don't think setCustomView is related to my question.

Comment: Re: Edit 3: even if it worked, that wouldn't generate the fade effect, wouldn't it?